# Logistic regression scoring: java.lang.NumberFormatException

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

I am using Spark 1.5 and I would like to use logistic regression model that I have saved from my training phase for scoring on new dataset.

Here is my sample data in libsvm file format:

1132106-2011-05-10 52:1 64:1 207:1 232:1 353:1 597:1

The first column is userid-purchase-date followed by index:val

```
val unseendata: RDD[LabeledPoint] = MLUtils.loadLibSVMFile(sc,unseendatafileName,  800)
```

Here is my scoring code:

```
    var resulting_scores = unseendata.map {  case LabeledPoint(label, features) =>
      var prediction = lrm.predict(features)
        (label.toString, prediction)
    }.toDF("id_date", "score")
```

I get this error:
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "1132106-2011-05-10"

How do I fix the formatting for my first column in the LabeledPoint? I want the string to be included as it is.

Here is the detailed error message:

> at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:2043)
>       at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.parseDouble(FloatingDecimal.java:110)
>       at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:538)
>       at scala.collection.immutable.StringLike$class.toDouble(StringLike.scala:232)
>       at scala.collection.immutable.StringOps.toDouble(StringOps.scala:31)
>       at org.apache.spark.mllib.util.MLUtils$$anonfun$4.apply(MLUtils.scala:80)
>       at org.apache.spark.mllib.util.MLUtils$$anonfun$4.apply(MLUtils.scala:78)
>       at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:328)
>       at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:328)
>       at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:328)
>       at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:328)
>       at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:328)
>       at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:328)
>       at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.insertAll(BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.java:119)
>       at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.SortShuffleWriter.write(SortShuffleWriter.scala:74)
>       at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:73)
>       at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:41)
>       at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:88)
>       at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:214)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Comment: Well the error says all. Is that label string a number ? Ofc, not. Your libsvm format is not valid !

Comment: I see. How can we load the file in the format that I have and do prediction/scoring?

Comment: how many labels do you have ?

Comment: The label has this format:  userid-purchase-date and  I have ~2 million rows in my libsvm file. Each row has unique userid-purchase-date value so roughly ~2 million labels.

Comment: 2 millions labels for 2 millions entries ?!? Have you followed any machine learning class ever ? How would you even classify that ?

Comment: I want to generate score for each combination of userid-purchase-date. Please refrain from personal comments.

Comment: Then your question is too broad to answer besides reading that format of file which you won't be able to use into logistic-regression, because your vectors will predicts labels they've learned from the your vector model and not scores on your labels. You should consider another solution and work on your purchase date format and use it as a feature instead.